# C# \ VS2010 \ Breakpoint is not hit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, breakpoints

Imagine this - You have a source code and a dll in debug mode. All symbols and PDBs are loaded correctly but breakpoint is not hit.

why?

(this is 3rd party code - function A calls function B in the same class - I manage to debug function A but when it calls function B it does not step in).

Comment: Are function A and B both managed code?

Comment: Are you attaching the debugger?

Comment: Do I have to imagine it?

Comment: 1. they both managed.  2. I'm attaching debugger.  3. you have to imagine that

Answer (score 1):

Right click, Location -> allow source code to be different from the original version.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to try turning CLR exceptions on. In the Exceptions dialog in VS, check the "Thrown" checkbox for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" and run again your application:

http://dotnettipoftheday.org/tips/break_when_exception_thrown.aspx

This way debugger will break on *every* exception, even if it is try-catch-ed in your code. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

(by the way, is the third party code x64 compiled?)

Try manually specifying the debugger types rather than just accepting the default of 'auto'.